# unable to capture json output showing in python output without print function

Tags: python-3.x

while executing program i am getting output directly on terminal without print function

```
import requests
import json

# URL of the Reuters page with the data
url = "https://www.reuters.com/markets/quote/USDEUR=X/"

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()
```

i am looking for below output to store in python variable

"market_data":[{"ric":"USDEUR=X","type":"Currency","name":"US Dollar/Euro FX Cross Rate","currency":"EUR","localName":null,"prev_day_close":0.9382,"open":0.9382,"ask":0.9385,"bid":0.9382,"expiration":null,"prev_settle_date":"2023-09-15","prev_settlement":0.9382,"open_interest":null,"ninety_day_volume":0,"originalRic":"USDEUR=X"}]

Comment: How, exactly, did you run this code?  Did you type `python myscript.py` at a command prompt, or did you run from inside an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: i have ran the code in linux terminal using command : `python myscript.py`

Comment: get help from this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/response-json-python-requests/
or please add your full code ?

Comment: Running your code snippets shows that the end-point is not returning a json response. It's likely you'll have to parse via `response.text` or `response.content`, or use a differnet library like `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: _i am getting output directly on terminal_ Are we supposed to guess what that output is?  Please show us.

Comment: thank you @Benedict , issue fixed with response.content

Comment: Need one help how can i filter only json data without has multiple formats like json , xml , html tags , i have share sample log from which i wanted to filter only below data : ```"market_data":[{"ric":"USDEUR=X","type":"Currency","name":"US Dollar/Euro FX Cross Rate","currency":"EUR","localName":null,"prev_day_close":0.9382,"open":0.9382,"ask":0.9385,"bid":0.9382,"expiration":null,"prev_settle_date":"2023-09-15","prev_settlement":0.9382,"open_interest":null,"ninety_day_volume":0,"originalRic":"USDEUR=X"}]```

python logs: https://gist.github.com/hemanth22/83291d4394f2a7ec717f77fe9b0fdbcd

Comment: @BitraHemanth I've worked with `beautifulsoup` to remove and structure `html` formatted data. I'm not sure what's the best solution here, but you might want to give it a shot :)